# Clarification for the definition of compact operators

Tags: banach-spaces

One of the definitions of compact operators is:

For any bounded sequence  $(x_{n})_{n\in \mathbb {N} } \in X$, the sequence $(Tx_{n})_{n\in \mathbb {N} }$ contains a converging subsequence.

Does this mean that the limit is in $Img(T)$? My problem is understanding exactly where the limit, which exists, resides, especially in light of the equivalent definition that $\overline{T(X_1)}$ is compact (where $X_1$ are all $x$ such that $||x||\leq 1$) - is the limit perhaps in $\overline{T(X_1)}$ or $T(X_1)$?

Comment: The limit is not necessarily an element in the image of $T$.

Comment: This is equivalent to asking if the image of the unit ball is compact. In non-trivial cases, it's not. Does this answer your question? [Compact Operator with Infinite rank Doesn't have a Closed Image](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754325/compact-operator-with-infinite-rank-doesnt-have-a-closed-image)

Comment: @TheoBendit But where is the limit then? Just in $\overline{T(X_1)}$?

Comment: Yes, in $\overline{T(X_1)}$, but not necessarily in $T(X_1)$.